# Proof of bijection between two infinite sets

Tags: real-analysis

If $g:X \rightarrow Y$ is a bijection, and $X$ is an infinite set, how would I prove that $Y$ is also an infinite set, using the following proposition: $X$ is infinite iff there is an injection $f: X \rightarrow X$ such that $f(X) \subsetneq X \iff f(X) \neq X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by infinite. If by infinite you mean not finite, you can do a proof by contradiction: Suppose $Y$ is finite; i.e., there exists a bijection $f:Y\rightarrow\{1,...,n\}$ for some natural number $n$. Then $f \circ g$ is bijection from  $X\rightarrow\{1,...,n\}$, so $X$ would be finite, a contradiction. Thus $Y$ is infinite.

If by infinite you mean that the set is in bijection with a proper subset of itself (such a set is called Dedekind-infinite), then suppose $i:X\rightarrow A$ is a bijection for some proper subset $A$ of $X$. Then consider the function $f=g \circ i \circ g^{-1}:Y\rightarrow Y$.  Since it is a composition of injections, it is injective. Further, its image is $g(A)$, which is a proper subset of $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have a bijection between X and Y means that the sets have the same cardinality. So if one is infinite the other one is infinite as well.

Or if this makes more intuitive sense, you can prove the contrapositive: If Y would be finite, and have $n$ elements, then X would have $n$ elements as well, and thus be finite as well. Since X is infinite, Y can therefore not be finite and must be infinite as well.

Answer (score 1):

Because $g$ is a bijection from $X$ to $Y$, $|X|=|Y|$ follows. Hence, $Y$ is also an infinite set.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $Y$ has $n$ elements then take $n+1$ elements from $X$ by Pigeonhole principle principle at least two elements from $X$ have the same image in $Y$ hence function isn't injective (1-1).